# Why does my Vite build process need to scan the host's hard drive?

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-sail

I am getting an error when starting a dev server:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/var/www/html/rootfs/host_mnt/c

I have a Laravel - Inertia - Vue3 application that I am trying to build with Vite for development.

##### From `vite.config.js`

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ]
});
```

##### devcontainer.json

```json
{
    "name": "Mangrove Development Environment",
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../docker-compose.yml"
    ],
    "service": "mangrove",
    "workspaceFolder": "/var/`your text`www/html",
    "settings": {},
    "customizations": {
       "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "felixfbecker.php-debug",
                "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare",
                "eamodio.gitlens",
                "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client",
                "mikestead.dotenv",
                "amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense",
                "ryannaddy.laravel-artisan",
                "onecentlin.laravel5-snippets",
                "onecentlin.laravel-blade",
                "EditorConfig.EditorConfig",
                "jcbuisson.vue",
                "redhat.vscode-yaml"
            ]
        }
    },
    "remoteUser": "sail",
    //"postCreateCommand": "chown -R 1000:1000 /var/www/html"
    "postCreateCommand": ""
    // "forwardPorts": [],
    // "runServices": [],
    // "shutdownAction": "none",
}
```

I tried using `"postCreateCommand": "chown -R 1000:1000 /var/www/html"` in the devcontainer.json file, but this simply tries to turn over ownership of every single file on my Windows system's hard drive.

I have also tried inserting

```json
server: {
    watch: {
        ignored: [
            "rootfs/**/*",
        ],
    }
}
```

Into the `vite.config.js` to perhaps ignore those files.

Comment: What are you using as your dev server? WSL? What is the full path of your local project?

Comment: I am using a windows system but trying to run my application through a Docker dev container using the VScode extension and ubuntu 22. I am using laravel sail to try run the vite command

Comment: I would recommend you switch to WSL, so you have your code in a linux system, instead of Windows

Comment: I will switch over to Ubuntu via wsl2 but I also have a teammate that has tried to build the app on multiple distros, yet runs into the same problem. I was just curious about the vite build process and why it would need to scan all those files

Comment: I am not exactly sure why you are having the issue, but if your teammate is also using `/var/www/html/rootfs/host_mnt/c` (mounting `C` disk) you both are going to have the same issue... the idea is to have the project on `/var/www/folder` or `/home/your_user/projects/folder`, etc. A place in the distro that is THE DISTRO not a Window's mounted disk